# Norm of the residual

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Let A be the tridiagonal ﬁnite-element matrix for the one-dimensional diﬀusion equation, let $Ax = 0, A \in R^{nxn}$ Implement the weighted-Jacobi and Gauss-Seidel iterations to solve $Ax = 0$. Consider relative reduction in residual norm $\frac{\|0−Ax^l\|}{\|0−Ax^{l−1}\|}, l$ is the number of iteration. What can you say about the “asymptotic” convergence as $l$ gets large? Does this depend on $n$?

My intuition says, that since we are getting closer to the solution with each iteration $\|0−Ax^l\|$ and $\|0−Ax^{l−1}\|$ would be equal for large $l$, so the fraction goes to $1$, and this doesn't seem to depend on $n$. But I'm not sure, can someone give me a formal proof?

Comment: How does $A$ depend on $n$?

Comment: @CarlChristian, $n$ is the size of $A$...

Comment: If we are free to choose the entries of the matrices independent of the dimension, then we can get any result we want. If on the other hand, there is an underlying pattern present, then definite conclusions are possible.

Comment: There is more than one matrix which fits the description which you have added. Are you thinking of the discrete Laplacian corresponding to a uniform grid with $n+1$ points?

Comment: @CarlChristian, thats right

Answer (score 1):

Without further information on $A$ there is no way to answer your questions. Regarding your intuition, depending on $A$, the methods may not even converge for every initial approximation, so the "getting closer to the solution with each iteration..." may not occur.